# Invalid Directory Item Count (It should be 3*673 instead of 3*674) while MacBook partition using Disk Utility

Tags: macos, partitioning, disk

I am trying to set up dual boot in my `MacBookPro`. When I am trying to make a partition from `Disk Utility` it is giving error,

> Checking multi-linked files.
>
> Checking catalog hierarchy.
>
> Invalid directory item count (It should be 32673 instead of 32674)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution from [this](http://osxdaily.com/2013/08/07/how-to-repair-a-mac-disk-with-fsck-from-single-user-mode/) post

Boot the Mac into Single User Mode by holding down `Command+S` during system boot. write,

> fsck -fy

Once fsck completes, if you see a “File system was modified” message, you need to **run again**,

> fsck -fy

After that you need to run,

> reboot